# lxml.etree.iterparse closes input file handler?

Tags: python, stringio, iterparse

filterous is [using](https://github.com/l0b0/filterous/blob/cc172cc54bd068a5f1de231e3567f4fe0bb5d2d1/filterous/filterous.py#L262) `iterparse` to parse a simple [XML `StringIO` object](https://github.com/l0b0/filterous/blob/cc172cc54bd068a5f1de231e3567f4fe0bb5d2d1/tests/tests.py#L56) in a [unit test](https://github.com/l0b0/filterous/blob/cc172cc54bd068a5f1de231e3567f4fe0bb5d2d1/tests/tests.py#L139). However, when trying to access the `StringIO` object afterwards, Python exits with a "`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`" message. According to the [`iterparse` documentation](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk), "Starting with lxml 2.3, the .close() method will also be called in the error case," but I get no error message or `Exception` from `iterparse`. My IO-foo is obviously not up to speed, so does anyone have suggestions?

The command and (hopefully) relevant code:

```
$ python2.6 setup.py test
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from filterous import filterous as package

setup(
    ...
    test_suite = 'tests.tests',
```

tests/tests.py:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import unittest

from filterous import filterous

XML = '''<posts tag="" total="3" ...'''

class TestSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.xml = StringIO(XML)
        self.result = StringIO()
    ...
    def test_empty_tag_not(self):
        """Empty tag; should get N results."""
        filterous.search(
            self.xml,
            self.result,
            {'ntag': [u'']},
            ['href'],
            False)
        self.assertEqual(
            len(self.result.getvalue().splitlines()),
            self.xml.getvalue().count('<post '))
```

filterous/filterous.py:

```
from lxml import etree
...
def search(file_pointer, out, terms, includes, human_readable = True):
    ...
    context = etree.iterparse(file_pointer, tag='posts')
```

Traceback:

```
ERROR: Empty tag; should get N results.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/dev/filterous/tests/tests.py", line 149, in test_empty_tag_not
    self.xml.getvalue().count('<post '))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

PS: The tests all ran fine on [2010-07-27](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=Filterous&version=0.8.2).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine with `StringIO`, try using that instead of `cStringIO`. No idea why it's getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

Docs-fu is the problem. What you quoted "Starting with lxml 2.3, the .close() method will also be called in the error case," is nothing to do with iterparse. It appears on your linked page *before* the section on iterparse. It is part of the docs for the target parser interface. It is referring to the close() method of the target (output!) object, nothing to do with your StringIO. In any case, you also seem to have ignored that little word *also*. Before 2.3, lxml closed the target object only if the parse was successful. Now it *also* closes it upon error.

Why do you want to "access" the StringIO object after parsing has finished?

**Update** By trying to access the database afterwards, do you mean all those self.xml.getvalue() calls in your tests? [Show the ferschlugginer traceback in your question so we don't need to guess!] If that's causing the problem (it does count as an IO operation), forget getvalue() ... if it were to work, wouldn't it return the (unconventionally named) (invariant) XML?